# DBCP2 initialization

Tags: java, spring-security, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm using DBCP2 with Spring Security (XML configuration). My problem is that everytime that I made a INSERT or UPDATE creates connections (initialSize = 100), so after a time I get "Too many connections".

I do not know if I doing something wrong in my configuration or in another step.

This is my configuration:

**1. springSecurity.xml file**

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
       <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
       <beans:property name="url" value="${bd.url}" />
       <beans:property name="username" value="${bd.user}" />
       <beans:property name="password" value="${bd.password}" />
       <beans:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
       <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="30" />
       <beans:property name="removeAbandonedOnBorrow" value="true" />
       <beans:property name="removeAbandonedOnMaintenance" value="true" />
       <beans:property name="initialSize" value="100" />
       <beans:property name="maxTotal" value="1000" />
       <beans:property name="maxIdle" value="50" />
       <beans:property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30" />        
   </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="npjt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" >
     <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="DAOEmail" class="general.Email"  >  
       <beans:property name="npjt" ref="npjt" />
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="DAOAddress" class="general.Address" >  
    <beans:property name="npjt" ref="npjt" />
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="DAOPhone" class="general.Phone" >  
    <beans:property name="npjt" ref="npjt" />
</beans:bean> 

<beans:bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

**2. DAO**

```
public interface DAOEmail{
    public void save(HashMap<String, String> params);
    public void update(HashMap<String, String> params);
}

public interface DAOPhone{
    public void save(HashMap<String, String> params);
    public void update(HashMap<String, String> params);
}

public interface DAOAddress{
    public void save(HashMap<String, String> params);
    public void update(HashMap<String, String> params);
}
```

**3. Calling from a Servlet**

```
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springSecurity.xml");
 DAOAddress dao = (DAOAddress) context.getBean("DAOAddress");
 dao.save(params);
 context.registerShutdownHook();
```

Same process per Servlet (Phone, email, address)

**4. Operations per file (Address, phone, email)**

```
public class Address implements DAOAddress {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt;

    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNpjt() {
        return npjt;
    }

    public void setNpjt(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt) {
        this.npjt = npjt;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(HashMap<String, String> params) {
       try { 
         ....
            npjt.update();  
         ....
       } catch (Exception e) {
            TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
       }
    }


@Transactional
    @Override
    public void update(HashMap<String, String> params) {
      try { 
         ....
            npjt.update();  
         ....
       } catch (Exception e) {
            TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
       }

    }
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: the "calling from a servlet" bit sends off a red flag for me. You seem to be creating an entire Spring application context for every call to the servlet.

Comment: Thanks for you time... I do the same process by servlet (DAOPhone, DAOAddress, DAOEmail),  I understand that I have to create a class to initialize the context just once? The above to avoid create and close the XML, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this value in datasource configuration

```
<beans:property name="initialSize" value="100" />
```

"initialSize" in "dataSource" bean is the initial number of connections that are created when the pool is started. That value in your configuration is "100". It is two high.

Remove that property to use default value (0) or use lower value can resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set the default value (0) but still my connections grow indefinitely (1 by 1). I have read that the connections are closed automatically but I still see them active. My question is I have to close de connections o is something wrong in my configuration???

Answer (score 0):

Try to use simplest configuration for datasource with minimum parameters, use default value for others as below:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"> 
       <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
       <beans:property name="url" value="${bd.url}" />
       <beans:property name="username" value="${bd.user}" />
       <beans:property name="password" value="${bd.password}" />
       <beans:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />     
   </beans:bean>
```

If above configuration can resolve your issue, add the other parameters one by one to check which parameter causes problem.

Hope above solution can help.

Comment: Thanks for you time... I did it but it didn't work, grows indefinitely...